# Searching video streaming apps for media content simultaneously

Tags: video, video-streaming, google-play-movies

I would like to search for videos to play on all of Netflix, Amazon Prime Video, Rai Play, and YouTube, simultaneously (ad I often cannot remember on which media service a given movie is to be found, and lose some time searching, and may need to locate and play a specific movie searched for quickly).

Is there a way in Android to cross search these services from a single place?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try https://www.justwatch.com (web site or app)